# A seemingly counterintuitive result on active and passive transformations of vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors, tensors, linear-transformations

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be an element of a vector space with Euclidean $R^3$ as the underlying set. Assume the standard Cartesian basis $\{\mathbf{e^{(1)}, e^{(2)}, e^{(3)}}\}$ on it.

Let $\mathbf{v^* = R v}$ be the vector obtained by an (active) transformation of $\mathbf{v}$ by the linear map $\mathbf{R}$. Assume that $\mathbf{R}$ is invertible (though this is not necessary).

In the standard basis, with summation implied (there is no need to distinguish covariant / contravariant components in Cartesian)
$$
v^*_i = R_{ij}v_j
$$

Now consider the action of another linear map $\mathbf{S}$ on the *vectors* of the standard basis, i.e., let
$$
\mathbf{e'^{(i)} = S e^{(i)}}
$$
This (passive) transformation yields a basis in which the components of $\mathbf{v}$
are given by
$$
v'_i = \beta_{ij} v_j
$$
where
$$
\beta_{ij} = \mathbf{e'^{(i)} \cdot e^{(j)}}
$$

Now, when I tried to find out the conditions on the linear maps $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ under which the components $v^*_i$ and $v'_i$ are numerically the same, I got the following counterintuitive sufficient condition.

$$
\mathbf{S = R^T}
$$

This is really perplexing, since I expected $\mathbf{S = R^{-1}}$. For example, for simple rotations, taking the inverse makes perfect sense - a rotation of the vector and rotation of the basis in the opposite direction give $v^*_i = v'_i$. Of course, in this case $R^{-1} = R^{T}$. But thinking of scaling and other transformations, it is hard to imagine why one would use $R^T$ on the basis to "undo" the effects of $R$ on the vector.

**Why is this so?**

Thank you.

(I am reasonably sure I didn't commit a blunder in arriving at $\mathbf{S = R^T}$ and also checked a few cases numerically. My apologies if this is trivial.)

Comment: on thing is a linear transformation and another thing is a change of basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the inner product)
\begin{align*}
  Sv &= \sum_i (Sv, e_i)e_i\\
     &= \sum_i \left(\sum_j v_je'_j, e_j\right)e_i\\
     &= \sum_i \left(\sum_j v_j(e'_j, e_j)\right)e_i\\
     &= \sum_i \left(\sum_j v_j\beta_{ji}\right)e_i
\end{align*}
So $(Sv)_i = \beta_{ji}v_j$, that is $R= S$.

Comment: I now see where I messed up - in the transformation formula. Thank you.